# New Ubuntu Modifications for Firefox did not install (Ubuntu 14.04, Firefox 54)

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, firefox, ubufox

I recently downloaded and installed the new Ubuntu Modifications, by upgrading `xul-ext-ubufox` to `3.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1`.

I can confirm that the package did upgrade to the latest version:

```
$ apt-cache policy xul-ext-ubufox
xul-ext-ubufox:
  Installed: 3.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Candidate: 3.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 3.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.8-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

When I opened Firefox 54 (I have not upgraded to 55 yet), I saw that the Ubuntu Modifications are still at 3.2 rather than 3.4:

[image: Fx 54, Add-ons Manager, Ubuntu Mods]

It gets weirder because I also have Firefox 52 ESR installed, and the Ubuntu Modifications in that one *did* update correctly:

[image: Fx 52 ESR, Add-ons Manager, Ubuntu Mods]

**So now, I cannot figure out how to get Ubuntu Modifications to update in my Fx 54 installation. Does anyone know how to do this?** (Or why they updated in one and not the other?)

When I create a new profile in Firefox 54, that new profile has the correct ubufox version. Old profiles also have correct version of Ubuntu Modifications. It is only the file I was using at the time I did the updates that remains stubbornly at version 3.2

At the time I performed the upgrade with Software Updater, I had Ubuntu Modifications disabled in Fx 54 and enabled in Fx 52 ESR. I do not know whether this matters.

I already tried removing the package (with Synaptic) and reinstalling it while Ubuntu Mods was active in Fx 54. No change. I also did `sudo apt-get install --purge --reinstall xul-ext-ubufox`. No change. Version 3.2 is still in Fx 54, and it is [still disabling multiprocessing (no e10s)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/16978901). I would like to upgrade Ubuntu Modifications to version 3.4 because it is a [security fix](https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3391-2/).

In case it is of any use, here is where I could find ubufox in my system:

```
$ locate ubufox
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/xul-ext-ubufox.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/icons/ubufox.svg
/usr/share/doc/xul-ext-ubufox
/usr/share/doc/xul-ext-ubufox/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/xul-ext-ubufox/copyright
/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/ubufox@ubuntu.com.xpi
/var/cache/apt/archives/xul-ext-ubufox_3.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/xul-ext-ubufox.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/xul-ext-ubufox.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/xul-ext-ubufox.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/xul-ext-ubufox.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/xul-ext-ubufox.preinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/xul-ext-ubufox.prerm
```

Comment: Firefox 54 is the package from Canonical that was installed in /usr/lib (the default installation when I installed Ubuntu in the first place). Firefox 52 I installed by downloading the tarball from Mozilla and installing in /opt. I keep separate profiles for each. It seems to me that if upgrading xul-ext-ubufox was going to fail, it should have done so in Fx 52 ESR rather than in 54.